# Improper integral comparison theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I have the following integral:
$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{x^5+5}dx$$
I have to use the comparison theorem to tell if it's convergent or divergent.

I have tried using $\frac{x}{x^5}=\frac{1}{x^4}$ as a function to compare *I* with, but $\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^4}dx$ is divergent and bigger than *I*: therefore I cannot make any conclusion about *I*. I could use $\frac{1}{x^5+5}$ as a function to compare, but I don't know how to integrate that, and it is only similar to *I* at $\infty$, not at $0$.

How should I tell if it's convergent or divergent?

Comment: "and it is only similar to I at $\infty$, not at $0$." is not really correct. Try graphing both functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparison with $\frac{1}{x^4}$ is the right way of doing this. Your integral is only improper at its upper boundary, and so the convergence there does not depend on the lower boundary: you could just as well test the convergence of the integral:

$$\int_c^{\infty}\frac{x}{x^5+5}dx$$

for some $c>0$ (e.g. $c=1$) - for which the function $\frac{1}{x^4}$ *can* be used. Due to convergence of:

$$\int_c^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^4}$$

the original integral also converges.

Comment: You could explicitly use the function $$f(x) := \begin{cases} x, & \text{if } x \in [0,1],  \\ x^{-4}, & \text{if } x > 1 \end{cases}$$ as a dominating functions, whose integral is convergent.

Comment: But how is the integral of $\frac{1}{x^4}$ convergent? If you separate it into two and take the limits, the part with $\infty$ goes to $0$, yes, but the part with $0$ goes to infinity, no?

$$\lim_{t → 0^+} \int_t^c \frac{1}{x^4} = \infty$$

Comment: My point is that you don't need to test the convergence of the integral on the interval $[0,c]$: the integral $\int_0^c\frac{x}{x^5+5}dx$ is proper as the interval is closed and the function that is being integrated is continuous on it. If you need one *single* function that will dominate your function across the whole interval $[0,\infty)$, then, as @ViktorGlombik said, you can patch it up in two parts.